# Rails 4 modify request parameters when custom mime-type given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, ruby-on-rails-4.1

To modify `params` when a controller received a request includes MessagePack, I wrote some code like this:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/x-mpac", :mpac

ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::DEFAULT_PARSERS.merge!(Mime::MPAC =>
  lambda do |contents|
    data = MessagePack.unpack(contents['data'])
    data.with_indifferent_access
  end
)

# Or

ActionController::Base.param_parsers[Mime::Type.lookup('application/x-mpac')] = lambda do |contents|
  data = MessagePack.unpack(contents['data'])
  data.with_indifferent_access
end
```

but this doesn't work in Rails 4.1.4

As another method, it is possible to using custom middleware. but custom middleware is not work in RSpec controller test.

Isn't there any other way?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Please provide a corpus, errors, and expected output.

Comment: For instance send request with parameter `{"data"=>"\x83\xA4name\xA6user18\xA8password\xACpassword1234\xACmachine_name\xABThe Machine"}` and a controller method expected to gave decoded params just like `{"name"=>"user18", "password"=>"password1234", "machine_name"=>"The Machine"}`. but actually this controller method was given `{"data"=>"\x83\xA4name\xA6user18\xA8password\xACpassword1234\xACmachine_name\xABThe Machine"}`. I'd like to know a method for interrupting ActionDispatch::ParamsParser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your code in an initializer and use:
MessagePack.unpack(contents)
instead of:
MessagePack.unpack(contents['data'])

Worked for me on rails 4.2.4